# How to fix 'bool' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

im new to python with django frame work and im developing three articles

i have tried to debug but i have failed and im getting this error "bool object has no attribute 'get"

## this is my models.py

```
 from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):# this new class articles inherits properties from models.model
    """docstring for Article"""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField( 'date published')
    likes = models.IntegerField()
    
    def __unicode__(self):
                    return self.get
```

and in my urls i have

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from article.views import article
#from django.shortcuts import redirect

urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^all/$', all, name='all'),
    url(r'^get/ (?P<article_id>\d+)/$', article, name='article'),
    ]
```

i expect to have a list of articles and when i click on the articles im directed to another page

but i get such an error

> System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
> May 28, 2019 - 15:38:06
> Django version 2.2.1, using settings 'finalreading.settings'
> Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
> Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
> Internal Server Error: /articles/all/
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\code\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
> File "C:\code\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 96, in **call**
> response = self.process_response(request, response)
> File "C:\code\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
> if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
> AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'get'
> [28/May/2019 15:38:15] "GET /articles/all/ HTTP/1.1" 500 57684

please help because i need to learn fast and work on the coming projects as well.

Comment: That error is not coming from this code, but from the view which you have not shown.

Comment: (Note that your `__unicode__` method is also broken, a) because there is no `self.get` field, and b) because Python 3 needs `__str__` not `__unicode__`.)

Comment: my views.py is from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from article.models import Article
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
# Create your views here.
 
def articles(request):
  return HttpResponse('articles.html',
        {'articles': Article.objects.all() })

def article(request, article_id=1):
  return HttpResponse('article.html',
        {'article': Article.objects.get(id=article_id) })

Comment: Don't post code in comments, update your question. But dirk has already given you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call your view `all` because it's a reserved function in python that returns a bool whether all elements of a list are `True` of not. Your urls.py contains this line:

```
url(r'^all/$', all, name='all'),
```

but you're not importing `all` so it's never hitting your view `all` but calling the python `all()`. But again, you should rename it to `article_list` or something like that and import that (and use that in urls.py).

Comment: when i change it to article_list i get a page not found error

Comment: its still gives an error of page not found when i change to article_list.please help out

Comment: The url should still be the same `/articles/all/` if you only renamed the view function. No reason you should get page not found if you didn’t change anything else.